# Jenkins JavaScript Testing and Code Coverage report

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, extjs, jenkins, gruntjs

We run a CI environment with Jenkins and the Project using ExtJS 5.1.1.

I try using Chutzpah test runner, using mocha framework JavaScript unit test.

With JavaScript test without ExtJS 5.1.1 testing run successfully.

But JavaScript with reference ext-all.js, there are no success. We have time out error in Blanket.js (error blanket_mocha.js line 5141‏) testing are not succeed and coverage.xml won't generate.

I'm looking for other way how run JavaScript test (ExtJS)  in Jenkins with mocha framework and have code coverage report generate.

We already have Grunt run in Jenkins to do JavaScript combine and minify.

Is this possible to using Grunt to run mocha test and generate coverage.xml  in Jenkins?

Please help me out if there is some other way to achieve the same thing. Any suggestion are highly appreciated.